# How to get different image from assets and assign it to image view in different table view cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, nfc

I am trying to add an image to my tableview cell by using an NFC reader session. So, my problem here is that every first reader session, I am getting the correct image in image view, but when I try the reader session the second time, I am stuck with two same last assigned image on both cells of my table view. I know it because of tableView.dequeueReusableCell method, but I am not sure which method to use to get correct image incorrect cells.

I have also attached a screenshot to make more clear of what I mean.

[In the screenshot is should see an image of a water bottle from my assets, but instead, I am getting the last assigned image to every cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqtZ9.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
            
            cell.nfcModel = arrData[indexPath.row]
            
            // IMG CELL
            cell.img.image = UIImage(named: name)
           
            
            return cell
           }
```

Comment: sorry I could not help with the NFC problem I worked a lot with tableView and how to display data from Web API

Comment: I hope the code example help

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert in NFC readers.

1.Create an array of products to store product data from NFC render.

2.in tableView `func cellForRowAt` you can render the images from
favoriteMovies using displayMovieImage function.
Sidenote:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        
        var favoriteMovies: [Movie] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        mainTableView.reloadData()
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if favoriteMovies.count == 0 {
            favoriteMovies.append(Movie(id: "tt0372784", title: "Batman Begins", year: "2005", imageUrl: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTM3OTc0MzM2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzUwMTI3._V1_SX300.jpg"))
        }
    }
    
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let moviecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
            
            let idx: Int = indexPath.row
            moviecell.tag = idx
            
            //title
            moviecell.movieTitle?.text = favoriteMovies[idx].title
            //year
            moviecell.movieYear?.text = favoriteMovies[idx].year
            // image
            displayMovieImage(idx, moviecell: moviecell)
            
            return moviecell
        }
    
        func displayMovieImage(_ row: Int, moviecell: CustomTableViewCell) {
            let url: String = (URL(string: favoriteMovies[row].imageUrl)?.absoluteString)!
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    moviecell.movieImageView?.image = image
                })
            }).resume()
        }
```